# How to reduce transparency for Openlayers using Map Composer?

Tags: openlayers-2, transparency-opacity

Increasing transparency of Openlayers will increase the contrast of others layers. For sure, it will increase the esthetical aspect of maps.

Comment: is there a question?

Comment: My question is in the title. Can we make Openlayers more transparent?

Comment: That's not a question.  OpenLayers is a library.  Not a layer.  What are you trying to make more transparent?  Layers in OL do support transparency.  And you have full control with CSS over actual controls.

Comment: Well, sorry if I said "OpenLayer is a layer". I'm not an expert in GIS.

Comment: Are you asking about OpenLayers for web mapping or the OpenLayers plugin for QGIS? (because you wrote about Map Composer which is a part of QGIS but tagged web-mapping)

Comment: "OpenLayers plugin for QGIS"
N.B. I'm not use for coding if that is required... For now, I'm more an "user friendly" type of user.